# keySet field in HashMap is null

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to loop over a `HashMap` with the `keySet()` method as below:

```
for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
    String value = bundle.get(key);
    ...
}
```

I use a lot of for-each loops on HashMaps in other parts of my code, but this one as a weird behavior: its size is 7 (what's normal) but `keySet`, `entrySet` and `values` are `null` (according to the Eclipse debugger)!

The "bundle" variable is instantiated and populated as follows (nothing original...):

```
Map <String, String> privVar;
Constructor(){
    privVar = new HashMap<String, String>();
}
public void add(String key, String value) {
    this.privVar.put(key, value);
}
```

Comment: If you are doing a lot of for-each loops on HashMaps I think you might want change your structure.

Comment: I agree with @Macarse. Also: *if* you want to loop over a `Map` and need both the keys and values, it's usually much better to loop over the `entrySet()` to avoid unnecessary lookups for each key.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Joachim, I will do that.
@Macarse: I put values in my maps key-value couples extracted from files (Excel spreadsheet) to apply a set of syntactical rules (regExp checks) before creating a new spreadsheet. Do you think maps aren't a good object to store this ?

Comment: So you are doing a Map<String, String> where the key is a row and the value is the regex?

Comment: No, no. The key is a key, and the value is a translation. It's quite an equivalent to a "ResourceBundle properties" file. And so the map is an equivalent for the ResourceBundle. That's what inspired me actually :)

Comment: and why are you iterating it?

Comment: I am iterating on entries to apply the .matches(regexp), and change the translation string if it fails, according to defined catcher/replacer regular expressions.

Comment: @Mathieu: SOrry I still don't understand, if you want, please create another question explaining what are you doing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What do you mean by `keySet`, `entrySet` and `values`? If you mean the internal fields of `HashMap`, then you should not look at them and need not care about them. They are used for caching.

For example in the Java 6 VM that I use `keySet()` is implemented like this:

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    Set<K> ks = keySet;
    return (ks != null ? ks : (keySet = new KeySet()));
}
```

So the fact that `keySet` is `null` is irrelevant. `keySet()` (the method) will never return `null`.

The same is true for `entrySet()` and `values()`.

Comment: It looks like the Eclipse debugger does display the desired information in the 'table' field.

Comment: It is returning null for me in Java 7 using     data.keySet().toArray();

where data is a HashMap<String,String> and it is not null

Comment: @tricknology: if that's the case, I suggest you post it as a new question (ideally with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)).