# why HashMap.keySet() doesn't return an empty Set

Tags: java, hashmap, keyset

Where do the keys in `keySet` come from? 
The class `KeySet` is a inner class of `HashMap`, it has the access to `HashMap` variables, but there is no direct variable like a `Set<K>` which stores only keys of the map to refer.

I can only find a `Entry<K,V>[]` table. But it have stored key and value.
Does the `keySet()` method do something when `new KeySet()` is called  to make the reference? May be  like:

```
for(Entry e : table) {
    keySet.put(e.getKey());
}
```

then the keySet stored keys,and when add or remove a key-value,it also add or remove the keys in `keySet` the same?

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    Set<K> ks = keySet;
    return (ks != null ? ks : (keySet = new KeySet()));
}
```

The source code shows just a `new KeySet()`, but why isn't it empty,but has the keys? To make it clearer:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put(1, 1);  //null
map.keySet();   //[1]
map.put(2, 2);  //[1,2]
map.remove(2);  //[1]
```

debug and breakpoint at each line,inspect each line and watch the keySet variable of the map will show the result above, right?

Once the keySet() called,the put and remove will take the same effect to the keySet,right? I've watched into the method put and remove of HashMap.

for "put()",if called addEntry -> createEntry -> after calling "table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<>(hash, key, value, e);" the keySet will add the key,

for "remove()" ->removeEntryForKey -> after calling table[i] = next; the key in keySet was removed, so i think there must be some association between table[] and keySet, and then i asked this question...

Comment: "i hope i have declared my question clearly" - not at all, I'm afraid. It's not clear whether you've already looked at the code and don't understand how it works, or whether you're trying to guess what the code would look like.

Comment: @JonSkeet eh...i want to understand,and  try to find a method like what i wrote when new KeySet() called to associate map-keys and keySet

Comment: Well have you looked at the code in the JDK?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes,but why "keySet = new KeySet()" doesn't return a empty Set,but a Set contains the map-keys

Comment: So *that's* your real question? Because it isn't at all clear from the question...

Comment: @JonSkeet right...let me change it... and why?

Comment: It *does* return an empty Set, if there is nothing in the HashMap.

Comment: @EJP i mean when the map is not empty....the set comes out not empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keySet field in HashMap is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272471/keyset-field-in-hashmap-is-null)

Answer (score 1):

`keySet()` returns an internal `Set` implementation backed by the `HashMap`. So, for example, calling `contains(key)` on that Set calls `containsKey(key)` on the backing `HashMap`.

It doesn't create an independent Set holding the keys of the original `HashMap` (as you suggested in your code snippet), since such a `Set` wouldn't be backed by the original `HashMap`, so changes in the `HashMap` won't be reflected in the `Set` and vice versa.

Here's the Java 6 implementation :

```
/**
 * Each of these fields are initialized to contain an instance of the
 * appropriate view the first time this view is requested.  The views are
 * stateless, so there's no reason to create more than one of each.
 */
transient volatile Set<K>        keySet = null;

public Set<K> keySet() {
    Set<K> ks = keySet;
    return (ks != null ? ks : (keySet = new KeySet()));
}

private final class KeySet extends AbstractSet<K> {
    public Iterator<K> iterator() {
        return newKeyIterator();
    }
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return containsKey(o);
    }
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return HashMap.this.removeEntryForKey(o) != null;
    }
    public void clear() {
        HashMap.this.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes,i've seen the source code,but i dont understand where the keys from,"return (ks != null ? ks : (keySet = new KeySet()));",i think this just return a new KeySet empty,but it's not,it's stored the map-keys in it.

Comment: @Just.Joke The keys are not stored in the `KeySet` instance. The methods of `KeySet` use the containing `HashMap` instance in order to access the keys.

Comment: you mean it's processed somewhere we can't see?i know that the inner class "KeySet" can hold the HashMap instance,and keySet just directly refer to the keys,but i can't find where the keys,i just found one is Entry[] table in HashMap, it can't be directly refer to, because it holds not only keys but values,another is Set<K> keySet in AbstractMap,but it's null after new HashMap, so i can't find a variable of Set<K> that keySet can directly refer to.then i thought is there some method the new KeySet() called that can get the keys out from the Entry[] table,but there is not either....

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the source code of `java.util.HashMap` to understand how this works.

The `keySet()` function actually returns a member variable of the `HashMap` instance as the following JDK source code got:

```
 public Set<K>  [More ...] keySet() {
     Set<K> ks = keySet;
     return (ks != null ? ks : (keySet = new KeySet()));
 }
```

Then the `keySet` is a member variable of an `HashMap` where its a locally defined class:

```
 private final class  [More ...] KeySet extends AbstractSet<K> {
     public Iterator<K>  [More ...] iterator() {
         return newKeyIterator();
     }

     public int  [More ...] size() {
         return size;
     }

     public boolean  [More ...] contains(Object o) {
         return containsKey(o);
     }

     public boolean  [More ...] remove(Object o) {
         return HashMap.this.removeEntryForKey(o) != null;
     }

     public void  [More ...] clear() {
         HashMap.this.clear();
     }

 }
```

So as you can see, it simply defines another "view" to the same data held in the `HashMap`. Nothing is duplicated so the consistency between the keySet view and the original map view is guaranteed.

Comment: i've seen the source code, but why "keySet = new KeySet()" can return a Set that contains the map-keys instead of a empty Set?

Comment: `keySet = new KeySet()` is a statement where the return value of the statement is the value from the right side of the `=` operand. That's why you can write something like `a = b = c` and it works; because `a = b = c` essentially is `a = (b = c)` where `(b = c)` returns the value of `c` (for java, a pointer to c if c is object and value of c if its primitive); and then `a` can be successfully assigned to the value of `c`.

Comment: sorry,i want to express that why the "new KeySet()" is not empty?when map is not empty,to call the method keySet(),it new a KeySet,but the keySet newed is not empty,it has stored the keys this map have.why it's not empty after only "new KeySet()"

Comment: As you can see, `new KeySet()` would actually refer to the wrapping map's elements. It's merely a structure to wrap the methods of a `Set` to make the code more organized. They can even have the map implementing the `Set` interface and return this if they decide to organized code in that way (of course it's not clean though).

Comment: eh,i think my question declaration isn't clear enough,my english is too bad... i'll update the question and try to declare clearer

Answer (score 0):

ok,i get the reason.the method really return a empty KeySet.but when break at it.the eclipse will call the method AbstractCollection.toString()...then the KeySet.iterator() method called.